# How can I query my data & store them by category in an array so as to display them by category in a TableView?

Tags: ios, swift

I wish to display my events by category in my TableView where each TableViewCell is a category, with its events found in a CollectionView embedded within the TableViewCell.

Here is a sample initialised prototype of what I want to achieve.

```
    var events = [Events]()
    var eventCategory = [EventCategory]()

    var testEvent1 = Events(id: 1, event_name: "PrototypeEvent", event_category: "Party", event_date: "10/06/19", event_img_url: "null")
    var testEvent2 = Events(id: 2, event_name: "PrototypeEvent2", event_category: "Music", event_date: "11/06/19", event_img_url: "null")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var eventArray = [testEvent1]
        var eventArray1 = [testEvent2]

        var category1 = EventCategory(title: "Party", events: eventArray)
        var category2 = EventCategory(title: "Music", events: eventArray1)
        eventCategory.append(category1)
        eventCategory.append(category2)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return eventCategory.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 245
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PopularCell", for: indexPath) as! PopularCell
        let category = eventCategory[indexPath.row]
        for event in category.events! {
            print("Event Name:\(event.event_name)")
        }
        cell.eventCategory = category

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to display data header section wise? what's your expected output?

Comment: No .. My expected output is described in the question

Comment: The question is pretty vague. While there is sample code, the question is marked Firebase but there's no Firebase code and it's not clear what exactly the issue is. It sounds like you want to store an array of Category classes where each Category would have a number of child events, and then use that array as a dataSource for your tableView. Is that correct? Can you tell us what the issue is with your code? Perhaps including a snippet of your Firebase structure and code would help clarify what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

make an `enum` for event_category:

```
enum EventCategory {
    case music
    case party
    ...
}
```

then use the grouping init of `Dictionary`

```
let eventsDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: events) { (element) -> EventCategory in
        return element.event_category
}
```

you will have a dictionary like this `[EventCategory: [Events]]`; it's will be an easy use for `tableView` `indexPath.row` to show a category for every row

Answer (score 1):

You can group the Events based on category using Dictionary's init, i.e.

**`init(grouping:by:)`**

> Creates a new dictionary whose keys are the groupings returned by the
>   given closure and whose values are arrays of the elements that
>   returned each key.

```
var groupedEventsDict = Dictionary(grouping: events) { $0.event_category }
```

`groupedEventsDict` will be of type `[String:[Events]]`, where `key` is the `event_category` and `value` is the `array of Events` lying under that `event_category`.

Now, since you need an `array` for `UITableViewDataSource`, you need to create an `array` from `groupedEventsDict`.

```
var groupedEventsArr = Dictionary(grouping: events) { $0.event_category }.compactMap({( $0.key, $0.value )})
```

So, your `dataSource` methods look something like:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return groupedEventsArr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PopularCell", for: indexPath)
    let (category, events) = self.groupedEventsArr[indexPath.row]
    print("Category: \(category)")
    events.forEach {
        print("Event Name:\($0.event_name)")
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: why you need to copy an answer?

Comment: @Alastar Well, I don't need to copy your answer. And if you can see, look at the answers. They're totally different.

Comment: Should I initialise the **var groupedEventsArr = Dictionary(grouping: events) { $0.event_category }.compactMap({( $0.key, $0.value )})** in the **viewDidLoad()** method ?

Comment: You can intialize it in `didSet` of events property as well. Or instead of using `events` property you can only use `groupedEventsArr`.

Comment: ``` let (category, events) = self.groupedEventsArr[indexPath.row] ``` causes the following error : ***Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'***

Comment: Your `groupedEventsArr` must be of type `[(String,[Events])]`. Change this and you will get the code working. And please avoid asking multiple questions for the same thing.