# How can I fix the following error : "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'" that appears in my code?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to group my **events** array by **event_category** using the Dictionary function `init(grouping:by:)`which is initialised in the groupedEventArray.
But when I try to access `let (category, events) = groupedEventArray[indexPath.row]` in the TableView's data source **cellForRowAt**, it causes an error : **Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'**

Here is the sample code I have being trying :

```
    var events = [Events]()

    var groupedEventArray = [Any]()

    var testEvent1 = Events(id: 1, event_name: "PrototypeEvent", event_category: "Party", event_date: "10/06/19", event_img_url: "null")

    var testEvent2 = Events(id: 2, event_name: "PrototypeEvent2", event_category: "Music", event_date: "11/06/19", event_img_url: "null")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        events.append(testEvent1)

        events.append(testEvent2)

        groupedEventArray = Dictionary(grouping: events) { $0.event_category }.compactMap({( $0.key, $0.value )})
        print(groupedEventArray)

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return groupedEventArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 245
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PopularCell", for: indexPath) as! PopularCell
        let (category, events) = groupedEventArray[indexPath.row] // Error : Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: ```Events``` has been changed to ```UIEvents```. Which swift version are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I query my data & store them by category in an array so as to display them by category in a TableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594668/how-can-i-query-my-data-store-them-by-category-in-an-array-so-as-to-display-th)

Comment: Kindly don't ask duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here since you made `groupedEventArray` as an array of `Any`, you can't assign it its subscript to a tuple. To fix the error, change type of the array to tuple itself.

ie,
Just change one line like

```
var groupedEventArray = [(String, [Events])]()
```

Everything remains same.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `groupedEventArray` as type `Dictionary<String, [Events]>`

```
var groupedEventArray = Dictionary<String, [Events]>()
```

Also drop the `compactMap`

```
groupedEventArray = Dictionary(grouping: events) { $0.event_category }
```

And access it using event category type

```
let partyEvents = groupedEventArray["Party"]
```